# Load data from same async function calling multiple times without promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have a async function like below(which gets data from url and loads in html elements)

```
function gethtml(URL, elementID) {      
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {      
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   }
  xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,true);   
  xmlhttp.send();       
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {         
    document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;            
    }
  }   
}
```

i need to call above function multiple times to load data into multiple html elements. for ex:

```
gethtml(URL1, 'element1');
gethtml(URL2, 'element2');
gethtml(URL3, 'element3');
```

I tried but, but it is loading only last URL3 data. I think data is overrding each time calling async function.
How to load data from same async function by calling muliple times?

Comment: declare `xmlhttp` as a local var ... i.e. first line in function should be `var xmlhttp;` - that way each call to `gethtml` doesn't overwrite the previous value of `xmlhttp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you only have one variable `xmlhttp`, which is declared as a global variable. And you overwrite it by calling `new XMLHttpRequest()` each time the function is called. It creates a new one, and specifies the callbacks, but then immediately goes and destroys that reference by creating a new object.

The fix is to keep a local `XMLHttpRequest` object *for each request*.

```
function gethtml(URL, elementID){
  // using the 'var' keyword makes these variables local in scope -
  // only accessible from this function
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {      
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  
    var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   
  }

  // ... 
}
```

Use the `var` keyword and it should work as expected.